# WPF ComboBox not displaying selected value

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have managed to bind ItemsSource and ComboBox lets me choose each option, but I cannot see which option has been chosen. ComboBox is just blank.
XAML code:

```
<ComboBox
  Name="Position"
  Grid.Row="5"
  SelectedValue="{Binding Position}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}"
  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBox}"
  Margin="15,10,15,10"
  FontSize="12"/>
```

Tried basic ComboBox (non-material design) and results are identical.

I will provide more code if you need it, but so far it seems that this control is just broken, it doesn't work as it should. I'm probably missing some small detail how to properly set it up.

Edit

ViewModel:

```cs
public class WindowAddEmployeesViewModel : EmployeesViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<PositionsViewModel> Positions { get; set; }

    new public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Base class contains things like FirstName, LastName, Position etc. `INotifyPropertyChanged` not implemented because Fody.PropertyChanged does it for me.

`PositionViewModel`:

```cs
public class PositionsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Position { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Position}";
    }
}
```

Edit

Switching `IsEditable` to `True` makes it visible, but i don't want user to be able to edit it.

Comment: Please share your view model (or class representing a data context for combobox binding). Did you also set `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski ```DisplayMemberPath``` and ```SelectedValuePath``` have not been set. In all guides i have found it just works by default. For me it's blank. User has to remember what has been clicked. Which is pretty bad.

Comment: Where is the selected `Position` defined?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski as i said in ```EmployeesViewModel```. It's the most generic class you can imagine so i decided to not provide so much code.

Comment: The question is do you set the Position object and do you set it with a Position from the list ? If not you might have to override the Equals and GetHashCode si the ComboBox can identify which item you want selected

Comment: I'm almost sure it's done correctly. As i said switching to IsEditable fixes the issue, but i just don't want to let user to edit it.

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you expect if you already decided where the issue is ...

Comment: I didn't ComboBox behaves oddly and i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misundestood the purpose of `SelectedValue`. You can bind to the `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`. It has nothing to do with the value being displayed by the `ComboBox`.

The displayed value can be defined by setting `ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath` to the desired property on the data model, but only when `ItemTemplate` is not defined. `DisplayMemberPath` is meant to replace the `DataTemplate` in simple scenarios.

You obviously want to set the `DisplayMemberPath`.
Also your current binding

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Position}" .../>
```

won't resolve (no matter the state of `ComboBox.IsEditable`) as the `DataContext` of the `ComboBox` is obviously the `WindowAddEmployeesViewModel` and not the `PositionsViewModel`. This could've been a hint that you are using `SelectedValue` wrong.

`SelectedItem`: the currently selected data model.

`SelectedValue`: returns the property's value on the `SelectedItem`, defined by `SelectedValuePath`.

`SelectedValuePath`: sets the path to the property, which should be the `SelectedValue` on the `SelectedItem`. Argument is a `string`.

`DisplayMemberPath`: sets the path to a property on each data model which is used to display the item in the `ComboBox`. Argument is a `string`.

**Data model**

```
public class PositionsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => Position;
}
```

**The view**

```
<!-- Since DisplayMemberPath="Position" the ComboBox will show the value of the Position property as its items -->
<ComboBox x:Name="PositionComboBox"
          DisplayMemberPath="Position"
          SelectedValuePath="Label"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}" />

<!-- 
  Displays the PositionsViewModel. Implicitly invokes PositionsViewModel.ToString().   
  The TextBox will therefore display the property value of `PositionsViewModel.Position`.
 -->
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=PositionComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" />

<!-- 
  Displays the SelectedValue of the ComboBox. This value is defined by ComboBox.SelectedValuePath.
  The TextBox will therefore display the property value of `PositionsViewModel.Label` 
-->
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=PositionComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" />
```

Comment: You are a life saver sir. Adding ```DisplayMemberPath="Position"``` fixed the issue. Interesting that guides absolutely skip that part, it's not something you can just guess on your own.